# simpmessagingtemplate.convertAndSendToUser with rabbitmq works slow

Tags: spring, websocket, rabbitmq, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm using spring 4 websocket stomp with rabbitmq. All works ok but simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser works very slow, call can take > 5 seconds. What can be a reason?